# Removing all member from Trello cards at once

Tags: trello, trello-cards

On Trello, I have multiple completed cards with 20+ people on each one. I would like to keep the card un-archived, but do not want the completed cards to clutter up people's to-do boards.
In future I will have them remove themselves from the card once completed. For now, is it possible to remove all members from a card at once?

Comment: I do not understand why you might want to keep the cards active in the board.  Archived cards are VERY easy to find when you need them.
Archived cards do not show up as To Do cards.  Hope you ind the best answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may make a COPY of the card(s) as you finish with them.

When you make a copy of a card you can include or exclude what is kept in the copy.  Keep the title, labels and comments. Uncheck Members.

This will make a copy of the original card without members.  Add back the one or two you wish to remain. Then delete (or archive). the original

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Butler Bot](https://trello.com/c/YfRXG0vU/19-what-is-butlerbot), which is a Trello automation tool, to do this. Depending on your criteria for a card being "complete", you can issue commands such as:

`when all of a card's checklists are completed, remove all members from the card`

or

`when the label "Done" is added to a card, remove all members from the card`

Etc. The tool is quite flexible and the developer (me) is quite responsive.